# Using regular expression in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have trouble in using regular expression.
My sample data is:

```
12 13 hello hiiii hhhhh

this doesnt have numeric so should be removed
Even this line should be excluded
`12` this line contains numeric shouldn't exclude
Hope even this line should be excluded

scala> val pattern = "[a-z][A-Z]".r
```

pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = [a-z][A-Z]

```
scala> val b = a.filter(line => !line.startsWith(pattern))
<console>:31: error: type mismatch;
```

found   : scala.util.matching.Regex
 required: String
         val b = a.filter(line => !line.startsWith(pattern))
                                                   ^

or if I use

```
scala> val b = a.filter(line => !line.startsWith("[a-z][A-Z]".r)).take(3)
```

> :29: error: type mismatch;
>   found   : scala.util.matching.Regex
>   required: String

```
     val b = a.filter(line => !line.startsWith("[a-z][A-Z]".r)).take(3)                                                                                                                                                            ^
```

I am actually not sure how exactly to use regex in spark. Please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex will only match with word that are composed by a lowercase and then by an uppercase. i.e. aA, bA, rF etc. So it shouln't discard any of the components of your list.

So you may want to change it to this:

```
[a-zA-Z]*
```

So it will match any word composed only by letters (both lower and uppercase)

Then regarding the match issue, you are using the wrong method, the proper one to match a regex is something like this:

```
val pattern = """[a-zA-Z]*""".r

val filtered = rdd.filter(line => !pattern.pattern.matcher(line).matches)
```

And here the output:

```
scala> filtered.foreach(println)
12
13
```

You can check the API for regex [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/util/matching/Regex.html)

Comment: This answer works!